# Replace first word of sentence to the end if it is "the"

Tags: php

If the first word of a sentence is "The" I want to replace it to the end with a comma before it so for example if I have the movie title: The Hunger Games, I want it to become: Hunger Games, The

Is this possible and if it is how can I get it working?

Comment: Take a look at `explode()` and decide whether or not it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<?
$str = 'The Hunger Games';
if (strtolower(substr($str,0,3)) == "the"){
    $str = trim(substr($str,3)).', The';
}
echo $str;
?>
```

**[WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/tks0vDqh)**

Comment: What if user enters "THE END"? He will get output "END, The"...

Comment: @Glavić just replace `', The'` with `', ' . substr($str,0,3)`

Comment: @WimMostmans: I know how to make working code, but answers should be valid for the future newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
echo custom_func('The Hunger Games');
```

**Function:**

```
function custom_func($s) {
    $s = trim(preg_replace('~\s+~', ' ', $s));
    $a = explode(' ', $s);
    if (strtolower($a[0]) != 'the' || count($a) < 2) return $s;
    $the = array_shift($a);
    return implode(' ', $a) . ', ' . $the;
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/54588).**

Comment: +1 for the do_magic function name. -1 for the do_magic function name.

Comment: well, you've removed the +1 part, but the -1 is still here. Try with a meaningful function name :)

Comment: @STTLCU: I think it is up to the user to rename function name, the answer is only for demonstration. I could easily wrote this example without the use of the function...